# Is there a standard library for Bash?

Tags: bash

Is there a standard library for Bash? something like Java standard library.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a BASH "library"?

Comment: Ask your doctor before using `bash` daily, as unintended side effects may occur.

Comment: If you mean a library of functions, then no.

Comment: @Blender:  And `zsh` causes zshts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think there are 'standard libraries' such as STL. 
There are various files that you can include.  For example:

- there are bash libraries to enable command-line completion for clear-case, git, etc
- there is `/etc/init.d/functions` which intended for use in `/etc/init.d` scripts (implementing services)
- There is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions` for use by scripts that are invoked when network interfaces (or whole network subsystem) change state.
- there are modules in `/etc/profile.d` that are automatically included for use by interactive shells

But I don't think that there are libraries implementing containers, iterators etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can try these 2 GitHub repoes, although they are not standard library, but it might be a good start.

[xsh](https://github.com/alexzhangs/xsh): a bash library framework.

[xsh-lib/core](https://github.com/xsh-lib/core): the core library of xsh.